# Which test runner works with VSTS and ASP.NET Core?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, mstest, xunit.net, azure-pipelines

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core web app and my aim is continuous integration and continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).  I've got to the point where the HelloWorld basic app builds and deploys and is up and running.

I am now at the stage where I want to add unit tests and have those executed as part of the build.

I don't need cross platform, and I have prior experience with MSTest so that was my first port of call.  However some initial investigation indicates that it isn't as straightforward as adding an MSTest project and away you go.  Particularly with the VSTS build.

So the question is what is the least painful way of getting a test framework in place and CD into Azure...

- MSTest
- xUnit
- Other?

Just to reiterate...I want to get tests running against my ASP.NET Core web app on a VSTS build server as part of my CI.  Has anyone successfully done this with one of the above frameworks without too many headaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xUnit works pretty well, I used it with `net452` target because when I first started the `netcoreapp1.0` wasn't supported yet though it should work by now.

Test project's `project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "description": "MyApplication.Web.Tests Class Library",
  "buildOptions": {
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [ ]
    }
  },
  "packOptions": {
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": ""
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "My.Application.Web": "1.0.0-*",
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta2-build3300",
    "Xunit2Should": "5.0.0",
    "Xunit2ShouldXml": "5.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Moq": "4.2.1510.2205"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Testing works both in VS 2015 and via command line with `dotnet test` (form a Test project's folder). This [Getting started with xUnit.net (.NET Core / ASP.NET Core)](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html) documentation may help you with details and you can always look up for the correct version of xunit for your verison of .NET/.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Did you get it working with a VSTS build?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't tried it yet, but since command line works there is no prerequisites to be installed / uploaded other than dotnet cli tools, runner etc. comes from nuget. I only configured it once on VSTS following this gudie http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure. But adding another commandline to run the tests should be a big challenge though

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MSTest TestFramework as well.
Here are some pointers:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/30/announcing-mstest-framework-support-for-net-core-rc2-asp-net-core-rc2/
Since then there have been a few more releases of MSTest and you can read about them here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/09/01/announcing-mstest-v2-framework-support-for-net-core-1-0-rtm/

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to Tseng's answer I wrote a blog post a couple of months ago that allows you to run/import/attach tests results to the build. It was written at the time the command was still dnx but adapting it I'm confident you can make it work properly as I did.
[blog post on how to setup xunit/donetcore/vsts together for unit testing](http://microsofttouch.fr/english/b/vince365/posts/units-tests-using-xunit-and-visual-studio-team-services-for-dnx-projects)